# Passing selected String in uiTableView from Array to uiLabel in new ViewController

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, xcode8, viewcontroller

I have my array, my `tableview` setup and the table shows the array of strings. 80+ strings in an array.

Now, I select a row, and obviously I want to pass the string in that row to a `uiLabel` in a secondary `ViewController`.

`placeTypes` is my declared array that is not in this posted code, just imagine an array with 84 strings! My `segueIdentifier` is A <- easy peasy. And `passedString` is the `uiLabel` that will receive the ..well...passed string data.

**TableView code**

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return placeTypes.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = placeTypes[indexPath.row]

    return cell 
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")

     performSegue(withIdentifier: "A", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "A" {
     //   let viewController = segue.destination as? ViewController

        // SOMEHOW PASS THE SELECTED STRING IN THE SELECTED ROW TO THE VIEW CONTROLLER

    }


}
```

**Okay and now my `ViewController` code**

```
 @IBOutlet weak var passedString: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

}
```

EDIT: I am still getting errors. With the updated prepare for segue I get use of unresolved Identifier for placeTypes[indexPath.row] and viewController is telling me there is no sendString variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Row number: \(indexPath.row)")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "A", sender: indexPath)
 }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "A" {
            if let viewController = segue.destination as ViewController,
               let indexPath = sender as IndexPath {
                viewController.sendString = placeTypes[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }
}


class ViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var passedString: UILabel!
    // Put the string you need to send in a separate var
    // You can't rely on the view controller being properly initalized
    var sendString: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let sendString = sendString {
            passedString.text = sendString
        }
    }
}
```

You can also take a look at legendary-potato: https://github.com/ryantxr/legendary-potato

Comment: Interesting. I am getting errors. Use of unresolved identifier for indexPath in perform segue.

Answer (score 0):

In did `didSelectRowAt` pass indexPath as sender and in `prepare` you can cast it to `IndexPath`. Try this.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "A", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "A" {

        let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {

             let yourText = placeTypes[indexPath.row]

             //   let viewController = segue.destination as? ViewController            
             // SOMEHOW PASS THE SELECTED STRING IN THE SELECTED ROW TO THE VIEW CONTROLLER
        }                                    
    }                
}
```